# Can I put a fraction of the form, $\frac{A}{(Bx^2+C)^2}$ into partial fractions?

Tags: integration, fractions

For example, $\dfrac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}$

This may be a dumb question as I'm pretty sure you can't, but then why not?

Comment: It IS a partial fraction.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I think you should expand that into an answer, quoting the definition of partial fraction decomposition that makes it clear that over the reals irreducible quadratic denominators are allowed.

Comment: @EthanBolker I would rather wait for clarification of the question. We know that both forms are partial fractions, but we don't know OP's expectations.

Comment: Are the complex numbers allowed?

Comment: If you want to confine yourself to real coefficients, then it depends on whether or not B and C have the same sign.